# Installed libncurses5-dev, but can't make menuconfig!

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

I'm new to Linux, I found some links in Internet to Build and install Kernel(Just want to play :-P). I installed required libraries(`ncurses libraries`), kernel headers(`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`). I don't know why I'm getting this error

```
batman@tx:~/kernel/linux$ sudo make menuconfig
scripts/kconfig/mconf  Kconfig
init/Kconfig:409: unexpected 'endchoice' within menu block
init/Kconfig:1759: unexpected end statement
make[1]: *** [menuconfig] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

If I run without `sudo` I'm getting like below

```
batman@tx:~/kernel/linux$ make menuconfig
 *** Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the
 *** required header files.
 *** 'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.
 *** 
 *** Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again.
 *** 
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Ok, I copied config file from `/boot/..`(which has already configurations by Ubuntu OS), so I want to continue without configuration. Again, I got this

```
batman@tx:~/kernel/linux$ make -j5 KDEB_PKGVERSION=1.veeru dep-pkg
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
init/Kconfig:409: unexpected 'endchoice' within menu block
init/Kconfig:1759: unexpected end statement
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.
```

In another video, they compiled the kernel like this

```
batman@tx:~/kernel/linux$ fakeroot make-kpkg -j5 --initrd --append-to-version=veeru kernel_image kernel_headers 
exec make kpkg_version=12.036+nmu3 -f /usr/share/kernel-package/ruleset/minimal.mk debian APPEND_TO_VERSION=veeru  INITRD=YES 
====== making target debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian [new prereqs: ]======
This is kernel package version 12.036+nmu3.
test -d debian             || mkdir debian
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘debian’: Permission denied
make: *** [debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian] Error 1
Failed to create a ./debian directory: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/make-kpkg line 984.
```

So, why I'm getting these errors, can someone explain that `make..` command(I know `-j` is for jobs). Most of the times I don't know what I'm doing(What's happening, why I'm doing like, etc). So, is there any articles for newbies(Had good knowledge on Unix OS) like me for GREAT start to know KERNEL stuff :-)

**EDIT:**

Distro: Ubuntu 14. I downloaded Kernel from kernel.org(4.2 Release).

Comment: Cross-post at https://askubuntu.com/questions/692153/installed-libncurses5-dev-but-cant-make-menuconfig and https://superuser.com/questions/994213/installed-libncurses5-dev-but-cant-make-menuconfig

Comment: (And a duplicate on Ask Ubuntu: duped there)

Comment: @Veerendra please choose *one* stack exchange site and delete the question from the others. If you choose this one, leave me a comment and we can reopen it. Also, please [edit] and tell us your distribution, where you got the kernel from, what steps you did before this (did you install the build dependencies?) etc.